# Where to find log messages printed in __anonymous() function

Tags: yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I have a recipe with a 'python __anonymous()' function, that prints a lot of information using bb.plain() and bb.debug().

When I bitbake the recipe, the messages contained within bb.plain() gets printed to stdout as expected, but after bitbake is done, I cannot find any output from neither bb.plain() nor bb.debug() in any of the log files.

I have similar logging in various other 'python do_...()' tasks, and all of that is present in the respective task log after bitbake completes.

Where can I find messages logged by the __anonymous function?

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous functions would execute at parsing time and the default log level is warning during parsing. plain and debug messages would only show if you run bitbake with the -D option and only when the recipe is reparsed.

Comment: If I run bitbake with the -D option, it seems to be printing the debug information for all recipes, so the information I am looking for is drowning in noise - Is there anyway to target a specific recipe for debug output?